# Add a css class to all eg. <p> tags at a specific point in the DOM via ruby

Tags: ruby, haml, markdown, middleman

I'm building a website with Middleman and would like to know if there is a way, in ruby, to add a css class - let's say, `para` - to all `%p` tags (I'm using haml) that are the direct descendant of `%section.page-section`. Is this possible? Or is there a better way to achieve this, considering haml?

**Reasons being**: a number of content editors are using a CMS/ dashboard to make edits in markdown (Redcarpet), which will be placed inside a yaml file; I can't rely on them adding classes within the markdown; the project, which I inherited, also uses the BEM methodology, so while I could simply use descendant selectors, I'd like to stick to the original brief; and on the JavaScript front, I'd prefer not to place extra load on the browser.

**My setup looks like this** (stripped back examples)

*data/some_page_section.yml*

```
markdown: |
  ## Heading

  Paragraph etc ...
```

*partials/_some_page_section.md.haml*

```
%section.page-section
  :markdown
    #{data.some_page_section.markdown}
```

*some_page.html.haml*

```
...

= partial "some_page_section"

...
```

**Note**

I've spent a good few hours searching for an answer and keep coming across Nokogiri, which seems like a good tool to easily navigate the DOM. However, it also appears to be aimed at scraping, and so I wonder whether this is the right tool for a job that otherwise *sounds* relatively straightforward...?

As is probably apparent, my ambit is front-end - just a caveat...

Comment: Rather than add a class to those things, normally you'd just style them with CSS. They don't need to have a class to be styled with CSS, you can select them based on your description. The selector would be `.page-section p`.  Could you be making this more complicated than it needs to be?  I guess you _could_ somehow put a custom processor in middleman that processes the HTML as it's produced and transforms it by adding those classes there.  And Nokogiri would be a good tool there. But it's a weird solution, just targetting what you want in css is better.

Comment: I agree descendant selectors are an easier solution. However, the strict adherence to BEM throughout the CSS means I'd rather not tamper with this approach (it's not really my place to either) - more so by the fact that any changes will on the most part be to the styling. I'll investigate a custom processor and if I come across a solution, I'll see if I can answer here. If you have any recommended resources at hand, that would be great too. Thanks...